# ¿Cómo actualizar datos en UPADATE INNER JOIN empleando sentencias preparadas PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy tratando de actualizar datos, uniendo dos tablas, la idea es solo actualizar datos en la tabla `sucursal` solamente si el cliente `id_cliente` pertenece a esa sucursal `id_cliente`. Ambas tablas tienen en su columna el `id_cliente`.

Tengo el siguiente planteamiento:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE sucursal s
                        SET
                            s.id_cliente = ?,
                            s.tipo = ?,
                            s.nombre = ?,
                            s.ubicacion = ?,
                            s.registro = ?
                        INNER JOIN cliente c ON s.id_cliente=c.id_cliente
                        WHERE s.id_sucursal = ? AND c.id_usuario=?");
$stmt->bind_param("issssii",
                    $id_cliente,
                    $tipo,
                    $nombre,
                    $ubicacion,
                    $registro,
                    $id_sucursal,
                    $id_usuario
                );
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

Línea del error: `$stmt->bind_param("issssii"....`

¿Cómo puedo actualizar los datos correctamente?

Tabla `sucursal`

```
id_sucursal    id_cliente    tipo    nombre    ubicacion    registro
    1              2          x        x           x           x
    2              3          x        x           x           x
    3              2          x        x           x           x
```

Tabla `cliente`

```
id_cliente    id_usuario    nombre
    1              1         Leo
    2              1         Pedro
    3              2         Mary
    4              3         Juan
```

Comment: Si ya tienes el valor de tu **$id_sucursal** y también de **$id_usuario**, ya que lo pasas por la función ```bind_param()``` como parámetros, para que hacer el ```INNER JOIN``` y no directamente ```$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE sucursal SET id_cliente = ?, tipo = ?, nombre = ?, ubicacion = ?, registro = ? WHERE id_sucursal = ? AND id_usuario=?");```, ya que solo te va actualizar si coincide el id_sucursall y id_usuario también sin hacer uso del ```INNER JOIN```.

Comment: @Diablo Lo que pasa amigo, es que no tengo el valor del `id_cliente` de la tabla `cliente `

Comment: Entonces amig@ la variable ```$id_cliente```de tu ```bind_param()``` de donde proviene?

Comment: @Diablo de un formulario `$id_cliente` que lo estoy rescatando así: `$id_cliente = $_POST["id_cliente"];` ya que se envía por medio de Ajax